# Strapi : Email setting fields seems to be disabled mode. How to enabled this

Tags: strapi

I am using latest version of strapi (v4.0.0)

In Email settings ---> fields seems to be disabled

How to enable this fields[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, those fields are `readonly`and are only configurable via the `plugins.js` file. Create the following file:

```js
// filepath - config/plugins.js

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  email: {
    config: {
      provider: 'sendmail',
      settings: {
        defaultFrom: 'myemail@protonmail.com',
        defaultReplyTo: 'myemail@protonmail.com',
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

Once done, just start the `strapi` server again using `yarn develop` command and you should see your values being reflected in the admin. Then you can even try sending out a test email using the `Send Test Email` button.

[image]

##### Reference:

- [Strapi Email Plugin](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/email.html#configure-the-plugin)

Comment: Email fields enabled. But Error when trying to Send a test email.                                                error: Couldn't send test email: can not connect to an                                                                                        y SMTP server.
How to add SMTP details

Comment: Yep, you need to have a SMTP server setup on your machine to send out any emails. If you don't wish to install a SMTP server on your machine, you could opt for 3rd mail senders like send grid.